# How to change target database server in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, try-catch, sql-server-2000

I was trying to use `TRY..CATCH` feature in SQL Server 2005's Stored Procedure but it didn't worked. I checked my version using `@@VERSION`, it displayed "MS SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.194 (Intel X86) " but when I clicked on Help->About, it displayed "9.00.1399.00" which clearly specifies that I have SQL Server 2005 installed.

I know that `TRY..CATCH` can only be used on SQL server 2005 or above..

My system might be using Sql Server 2000 as source database or something like that, I might be wrong in describing. How to change it then..

Comment: `Help -> About` would return the version of SQL Server Management Studio (the application you are using to run the SQL in), not of the SQL Server it is connected to.

Answer (score 3):

After re-reading your question, you clearly have SQL Server 2005 client tools (SSMS) installed, and have your database on a SQL Server 2000 server, so you cannot use `TRY..CATCH`. Period.

Assuming you really do have a SQL Server 2005 server, have you ensured the specific database has its compatibility level set to 90 (SQL Server 2005)?

Right click database->Properties->Compatibility level

This can happen if you upgrade the server and forget to upgrade the database compatibility level.

Comment: Thanks Mitch but in Compatibility Level I have only two options coming in. 1. SQL Server 7.0 and 2. SQL Server 2000(80). I don't have the option of setting it to SQL Server 2005 (or 90).

Comment: @Ajit D: then you don't have SQL Server 2005, obviously - your database server is a SQL Server 2000, and on that version, you cannot use `TRY....CATCH` - you need to upgrade!

Answer (score 2):

- `help..about` gives you the version of the client tools (SSMS)
- `SELECT @@VERSION` gives you server version

If the server version is 8.x then you have SQL Server 2000 which does not support TRY/CATCH. No amount of fiddling with Compatibility level will fix this.

You have 3 practical options

- Don't use TRY/CATCH
- Upgrade your server version
- Install a names SQL Server 2005 instance on the same box